# How can I disable a specific date in daterangepicker?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I want disable the date `9th of September 2017` in my daterangepicker:

```js
var date = new Date();
var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
var currentDate = date.getDate();
var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
    , dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    , startDate: moment(date).add(1,'days')
    , endDate: moment(date).add(2,'days')
    , datesDisabled:["17-09-09"]
    , locale: {
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />
```

But the date is not disabled in my calender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[bootstrap-daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) doesn't have **datesDisabled** option. Instead this option belongs to [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/).

With **daterangepicker** you can use the **[isInvalidDate](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config)** option:

```
isInvalidDate: function(ele) {
    var currDate = moment(ele._d).format('YY-MM-DD');
    return ["17-09-09"].indexOf(currDate) != -1;
}
```

The snippet:

```js
var date = new Date();
var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
var currentDate = date.getDate();
var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
    , dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    , startDate: moment(date).add(1,'days')
    , endDate: moment(date).add(2,'days')
    , isInvalidDate: function(ele) {
        var currDate = moment(ele._d).format('YY-MM-DD');
        return ["17-09-09"].indexOf(currDate) != -1;
    }
    , locale: {
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />


<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />
```

Comment: It is working. The problem is, that I am still able to write the 09.09.2017 into the input field

Comment: And I can also can select a range from 07.09.2017 to 12.09.2017. This should actually not be possible, because there is a disabled day in that range

Comment: These two are others points. Give me time and I'll add these other features. Thanks

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thank you very much

Comment: @gaetanoM I know, pretty old, but do you know which are those options? I'm using react-bootstrap-daterangepicker which is a wrapper of daterangepicker but I cannot figure how not to let the user wrap invalid dates. Any idea to share?